# Angular, unable to get list of values from a webservice (JSON)

Tags: arrays, json, angular, web-services, angular9

I'm trying to get a kids' list from JSON webservice, amid logging in I get a JSON response of name.... and the kids list for a specific doctor. I have the response in the console but for some reason when I try to display it in the HTML file I fail to do it.
Here's my kidsdetails.component.ts:

```
import {KidsService} from '../../service/kids.service';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {UserService} from '../../service/user.service';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogConfig} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {environment} from '../../../environments/environment';
import {ToastrService} from 'ngx-toastr';
import {Doctor} from '../../model/doctor';
import {Kid} from '../../model/kid';
import {AppComponent} from '../../app.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './kidsdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./kidsdetails.component.css']
})
export class KidsdetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  public kids : Array<Kid> = [];

  // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name max-line-length
  constructor(private service: KidsService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              // tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
              private _auth: UserService,
              private toastr: ToastrService) {
  }

  imageServer = `${environment.uploadWebServices}/upload/`;


  doctors: [];
  doctor;
  notes: [];
  selectedKid;
  info = false;
  game = false;
  advancement = false;
  personal = false;

  array: Array<any>;
  valueEditor = '';

  games: Array<any>;
  moyenne = 0;
  pin = '';
  isCollapsed = true;

  doc:Array<Doctor>=[];
  kid;
  selectedParent;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.array = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
      this.array.push(i + 1);
    }
    this.getKidsList();
    this.valueEditor = '';
  }

  getKidsList() {
    this.kid=this.kids;
  }
        /* this.doctor = res;
         this.doctors.forEach((doctor: Array<any>) => {
           console.log('doc', doctor);
           if (doctor['kidsinformation']) {
             doctor['kidsinformation'].forEach((kid) => {
               // el.photo
             this.service.getKidImage(kid.photo).subscribe(
               image => {
                 // console.log('image', image);
               },
               err => {
                 // console.warn('error', err);
                 if (err.status === 200) {
                   const img = err.error.text;
                   kid.photo = 'data:image/lpeg;base64,' + img;
                   // console.log("img", img)
                 }
               }
             );
           });
           }
         });
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log('err', err);
      }
    );*/
  openKid(kid) {
    this.games = [];
    this.moyenne = 0;
    console.log('kid', kid);
    this.selectedKid = kid;
    this.info = true;
    this.game = false;
    this.service.getUser(this.selectedKid.idUser).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.selectedParent = res;
      }
    )
    this.service.getKidGames(kid.idUser, kid.id).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log('games', res);
        this.games = res as Array<any>;
        this.games.forEach((el) => {
          this.moyenne += el.gameScore;
        });
        this.moyenne = Math.floor(this.moyenne / this.games.length);
      },
      (err) => {
        console.log('error occured', err);
      }
    );
    document.querySelector('#m').classList.add('is-active');
  }

  openNotes() {
    this.notes = [];
    // this.selectedKid = kid;
    /*this.service.getKidNotes(this.selectedKid.idUser, this.selectedKid.id).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        console.log('notes', res);
        this.notes = res as [];
      }, (err) => {
        console.log('error occured', err);
    });*/
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`kids/${this.selectedKid.idUser}/${this.selectedKid.id}/notes`);
  }

  closePopup() {
    document.querySelector('#m').classList.remove('is-active');
  }

  goToInfo() {
    this.info = true;
    this.game = false;
    this.personal = false;
    this.advancement = false;
  }

  goToGames() {
    this.info = false;
    this.game = true;
    this.personal = false;
    this.advancement = false;
  }

  goToAdvancement() {
    this.info = false;
    this.game = false;
    this.personal = false;
    this.advancement = true;
  }

  goToPersonalNotes() {
    this.info = false;
    this.game = false;
    this.personal = true;
    this.advancement = false;
  }

  logout() {
    this._auth.logout();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/authentication/login');
  }

  addKid() {
    document.querySelector('#add').classList.add('is-active');
  }

  onCreate() {
    document.querySelector('#code').classList.add('is-active');
  }

  closeCodePopup() {
    document.querySelector('#code').classList.remove('is-active');
  }

  savePin() {
    console.log('pin is', this.pin);
    this.service.consumeKid(this.pin).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.getKidsList();
        this.pin = '';
        this.toastr.success('The child was added successfully');
        this.closeCodePopup();
      },
      (err) => {
        this.toastr.error('A problem occurred while adding the child');
        // console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }

  getEditorText() {
    // kidId , text
    // return this.http.post("url", {  }, { headers : json + authorization })
    console.log('text ', this.valueEditor);
    if (this.valueEditor !== '') {
      this.service.addNote(this.selectedKid.id, this.selectedKid.idUser, this.valueEditor).subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(' saved note , res => ', res);
          this.toastr.success('Note was added successfully');
        },
        err => {
          console.log('error saving notes', err);
          this.toastr.error('There was an error adding the note');
        }
      );
    }
  }

  updateInput(e) {
    this.valueEditor = e;
  }


  showAllNotes() {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
    this.router.navigate['kid/notes'];
  }

  toggleCollapse() {
    this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed;
  }
}
```

This is my kidsdetails.component.html

```
  <div class="row mt-4">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <a (click)="logout()"
         style="padding:15px 20px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #c8c8c8; color: white; cursor: pointer">
        <i class="fa fa-power-off"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 mb-5">
      <p class="text-center h2" style="color: #EF6E28; font-weight: 700">KIDS LIST</p>
    </div>
    <!--div class="col-md-4" style="display: flex">
      <div style="margin: 0 auto"></div>
      <div>
        <a
          style="padding:15px 20px; border-radius: 50%; background-color: #EF6E28; color: white; cursor: pointer">
          <i class="fa  fa-plus"></i>

        </a>
      </div>
    </div-->
    <div class="col-md-4" style="display: flex">
      <div style="margin: 0 auto"></div>
      <button id="circle" style="color: white; cursor: pointer"
              mat-raised-button (click)="onCreate()">
        <i class="fa  fa-plus"></i>

      </button>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10">




      <!--div [(ngModel)]="doctor.Kids"></div-->



        <div *ngFor="let k of kids" class="col-md-6">

      <!--pre>
        {{kids | json}}
      </pre-->
           <!--a href="/kidsinformation/kid/{{doctor.id}}/{{kid.id}}"-->
          <a (click)="openKid(k)" style="cursor: pointer">
            <div class="card mb-3" style="max-width: 540px;">
              <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <!--img src="{{imageServer}}{{kid.photo}}" style="height: 100%" class="card-img" alt="..."-->
                  <img *ngIf="k.gender == 1" src="assets/Girl.png" style="height: 100%" class="card-img" slot="start">
                  <img *ngIf="k.gender == 0" src="assets/Boy.png" style="height: 100%" class="card-img" slot="start">

                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div style="display: flex">
                      <h3 class="card-title text-info"><strong>{{k.nickName}}</strong></h3>
                      <div style="margin: 0 auto"></div>
                      <h3 class="card-title text-secondary">{{k.age}}</h3>
                    </div>

                    <p class="card-text" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important"><small class="text-muted"></small></p>
                    <div style="display: flex">
                      <p class="card-text" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
                        <!--Parent phone number here -->
                        <small class="text-muted"></small>

                      </p>
                      <div style="margin: 0 auto"></div>
                      <p class="card-text" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">

                        <small class="text-right gender girl" *ngIf="k.gender == 1">Girl</small>
                        <small class="text-right gender boy" *ngIf="k.gender == 0">Boy</small>
                      </p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


<div class="col-md-1"></div>


<div class="modal" id="m">
  <div class="modal-background" (click)="closePopup()"></div>
  <div class="modal-card">

    <div class="container" style="background-color: #E9E9E9">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <img style="width: 80px; display: block; margin: auto" src="assets/logoSghartoon.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
          <div class="tabs">
            <div id="tab3" class="tab">
              <ul style="font-size: 1.5rem" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="tabulation tab-info mr-3"><a (click)="goToInfo()">Kid's info</a></li>
                <li class="tabulation tab-game mr-3"><a (click)="goToGames()">Games</a></li>
                <!--li class="tabulation tab-advance mr-3"><a (click)="goToAdvancement()">Advancement</a></li-->
                <li class="tabulation tab-personal mr-3"><a (click)="goToPersonalNotes()">Personal notes</a></li>
              </ul>

              <!-- Kid's info Start-->
              <div class="tab-content" *ngIf="info">
                <div class="container" style="margin-top: -1px">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5 pl-5 pr-2">
                      <div class="row pb-2">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                          <div>


                          </div>
                          <!--img width="250px" src="{{imageServer}}{{selectedKid.photo}}" alt=""-->
                          <img *ngIf="selectedKid.gender == 1" src="assets/Girl.png" style="height: 100%"
                               class="card-img" slot="start">
                          <img *ngIf="selectedKid.gender == 0" src="assets/Boy.png" style="height: 100%"
                               class="card-img" slot="start">
                        </div>

                        <div *ngIf="selectedKid" class="col-md-8">
                          <div class="card-body">
                            <div style="display: flex">
                              <h3 class="card-title h1 text-info">
                                <strong>{{selectedKid.nickName}} &emsp; </strong>
                                <strong style="font-size: 2.5rem !important;" class="text-right h1 gender girl"
                                        *ngIf="selectedKid.gender == 1">Girl</strong>
                                <strong style="font-size: 2.5rem !important;" class="text-right h1 gender boy"
                                        *ngIf="selectedKid.gender == 0">Boy</strong>
                              </h3>
                              <div style="margin: 0 auto"></div>
                              <h3 class="card-title text-secondary" style="font-size: 2rem">
                                <strong>{{selectedKid.age}} Years old</strong>
                              </h3>
                            </div>

                            <p class="card-text" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important; font-size: 2rem; color: gray">
                            </p>
                            <div style="display: flex">


                              <div style="margin: 0 auto"></div>
                              <p class="card-text" style="margin-bottom: 0 !important;">
                              </p>
                              <!--Parent phone number here -->
                              <div>
                                <small class="phone-number">
                                  <i id="phone" class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                                  Phone number: {{selectedParent.phoneNumber}} </small>
                              </div>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!--  Kid's info End-->
              <!-- Games Start-->
              <div class="tab-content" *ngIf="game" style="border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; background-color: #EF6E28">
                <div class="container" style="margin-top: -1px">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-5 pr-2">
                      <div class="row pb-2">
                        <div class="col-md-2"
                             style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto; padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0">
                          <div style="text-align: center">
                            <span class="h1 text-center text-light"
                                  style="font-size: 3rem"> <strong>{{moyenne}}</strong></span>
                          </div>
                          <div style="text-align: center">
                            <span class="h3 text-center text-light"><strong>Total Score</strong></span>
                          </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                          <div class="card-body card-body-modal">
                            <div style="background-color: white; padding: 20px; border-radius: 10px"
                                 class="table-wrapper-scroll-y my-custom-scrollbar">
                              <table class="table table-striped mb-0">
                                <thead style="background-color: #E9E9E9; border-radius: 25px">
                                <th>Game name</th>
                                <!--th>Type</th-->
                                <th>Timing</th>
                                <th>Score</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr *ngFor="let game of games" style="background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #EF6E28">
                                  <td class="first_td"> {{game.idTestGame | gameName}} </td>
                                  <!--td>{{game}}</td-->
                                  <td>{{game.timeScore}}sec</td>
                                  <td class="last_td"> {{game.gameScore}} </td>

                                  <td *ngIf="isCollapsed">
                                    <button
                                      (click)="toggleCollapse()" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Show more details
                                    </button>
                                  </td>

                                  <td *ngIf="!isCollapsed">
                                    <button
                                      (click)="toggleCollapse()" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Show less details
                                    </button>
                                  </td>
                                  <div *ngIf="!isCollapsed">
                                    <img src="assets/gameScreenshot.PNG" style="height: auto" class="card-img">
                                  </div>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                              </table>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!--  Games End-->

            <!-- advancement Start-->
            <!--div class="tab-content" *ngIf="advancement"
                 style="border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; margin-bottom: -1px ;background-color: #00A5D2">
            </div-->
            <!--  advancement End-->

            <!-- Presonal notes start -->
            <div class="tab-content" *ngIf="personal"
                 style="border-bottom-left-radius: 10px; background-color: #ffdf00">
              <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: -1px">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 mt-2 mb-2 pr-2 pl-2">
                    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:#E9E9E9; height: 345px ;border-radius: 10px">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-2" style="margin-top: auto; margin-bottom: auto">
                          <button style="margin-left: 10px; border-radius: 10px;" kendoButton (click)="openNotes()"
                                  [primary]="true">Show all notes
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                          <div>
                            <kendo-editor [value]="valueEditor" (valueChange)="updateInput($event)"
                                          style="height: 300px; margin-top: 5px"></kendo-editor>
                          </div>
                          <div style="display: flex">
                            <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"></div>
                            <div>
                              <button style="border-radius: 10px;margin-top:5px; margin-bottom: 20px" kendoButton
                                      [primary]="true" [disabled]="valueEditor==''" (click)="getEditorText()"> getText
                              </button>

                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngFor="let note of notes">
                          <div>
                            <pre> {{note | json }} </pre>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Presonal notes End -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Child add via pin code start -->
<div class="modal" id="code">
  <div class="modal-background" (click)="closeCodePopup()"></div>
  <div class="modal-card" style="width: 40%">
    <header class="modal-card-head">
      <p class="modal-card-title">Add a kid</p>
      <button class="close" (click)="closeCodePopup()"><i class="far fa-times-circle"></i></button>
    </header>
    <form #f="ngForm">
      <section class="modal-card-body">

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="">Pin code</label>
          <input type="text" #p="ngModel" required [(ngModel)]="pin" name="pin" placeholder="PIN" class="form-control">
          <div class="text-danger" *ngIf="p.touched && p.invalid"> Pin code is required!</div>
        </div>

      </section>
      <footer class="modal-card-foot">
        <button class="btn " [disabled]="f.invalid" style="background-color: #EF6E28; color: white" (click)="savePin()">
          Save changes
        </button>
        <button class="btn" (click)="closeCodePopup()">Cancel</button>
      </footer>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Child add via pin code end -->
```

This is the Doctors model:

```
export class Doctor {
  public createdAt:string ;
  public firstName:string;
  public id: string;
  public kids: Array<Kid>;
  public lastName:string;
  public login: string;
  public mail: string;
  public password: string;
  public phoneNumber:string;
  public photo: string;
  public token: string;
  public updatedAt: string;


}
```

This is the service: I get the doctors by the method *getUsers()* because I don't have direct access to the kid's list:

```
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
import {UserService} from './user.service';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class KidsService {

  private readonly proxy: string = environment.usersWebServices;
  private readonly proxyTrace: string = environment.traceWebServices;
  private readonly imageServer: string = environment.uploadWebServices;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
              private service: UserService,
              private route: Router) { }

  private get JsonType() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ Authorization : 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access') });
   // headers.append({'Authorization': ''});
    return headers;
  }

  public getUsers() {
     return this.http.get(`${this.proxy}/doctor`, { headers : this.JsonType  });



  }

  getUser(id) {
 // authentication/id
    return this.http.get(`${this.proxy}/user/${id}`, { headers : this.JsonType  });
  }
  onLogout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    this.route.navigateByUrl('/authentication/login');
  }

  getKidGames( idUser, idKid  ) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.proxyTrace}/dataoutput/evaluation/${idUser}/${idKid}`, { headers : this.JsonType  });
  }


  consumeKid(pinCode) {
    const idDoctor = this.service.getUserDetails().unique_name;
    return this.http.get(`${this.proxy}/kidcode/consume/${pinCode}/${idDoctor}`);
  }

  addNote( idKid, idUser, text ) {
    const obj = { text , idKid , idUser};
    return this.http.post(`${this.proxy}/doctornote`, obj, { headers : this.JsonType });
  }

  getKidNotes(idUser, idKid) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.proxy}/doctornote/bykid/${idUser}/${idKid}`, {headers : this.JsonType});
  }

  getKidImage(id) {
    return this.http.get(`${this.imageServer}/upload/${id}`, {headers : this.JsonType});
  }
}
```

Comment: Where are you assigning the value to the array `this.kids` from the web service? it seems it's just an empty array. `public kids : Array<Kid> = [];`

Comment: `@Niladri I added the kids.service.ts like I said I don't have direct access to the kid's list, the response of the Webservice that returns the JSON values comes from login.component.ts and then I'll have to display it in another component which is, in this case, kidsketails.component.html.

Comment: I fixed the problem, I created two methods in **kids.service.ts** `fillkids(kid: Array<Kid>)` that returns a kid and `getKids(): Array <Kid>` that returns the kids list. I then went back to **kidsdetails.component.ts** and wrote in `getKidsList()`  `{console.log ('docotr kid', this.kidsservice.getKids());} `

Comment: But please don't forget to add `sessionStorage.getItem()` in the **service.ts**, or all the data that was stored is going to be lost because Agular doesn't keep the data amid refreshing the page.